# Image transfer from Android app to pc server via sockets

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send an image from my mobile's gallery to a java pc server through tcp socket. I tried the following code which some claim that they got the output but I am getting an error on the server-side. I will mention the error also please help me in fixing the error. I am new to java and android programming.

Client side code:

```
package com.example.sclient;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SendfileActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("34");
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
        System.out.println("36");
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bBrowse))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        System.out.println("40");
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                                SELECT_PICTURE);
                        System.out.println("47");
                    }
                });
        ;
        System.out.println("51");
        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        final TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Socket sock;
                try {
                    //sock = new Socket("MY_PCs_IP", 8000); 
                    sock = new Socket("192.168.0.12", 8000);
                    System.out.println("Connecting...");

                     // sendfile
                          File myFile = new File (selectedImagePath); 
                          byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                          BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                          bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
                          System.out.println("Sending...");
                          os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                          os.flush();


                        sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }
        });
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPath);
                path.setText("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Server code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FileServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;

        // create socket
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(8000);
        while (true) {
          System.out.println("Waiting...");

          Socket sock = servsock.accept();
          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

       // receive file
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Gustavo\\Desktop\\WebOffice.jpg"); // destination path and name of file
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            // Recibe el File JPG
            do {
               bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end-start);
            bos.close();


            out.close();


          sock.close();
          }
    }   
}
```

Error :
   The error that I am getting is in this line  "bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);" in the server side that the array index is out of bound. Both the app and the server are getting connected but the data flow is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file to base64 and send file to your server.